# Continuous functions vanishing at infinity is always integrable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, lp-spaces

Let $$C_{0}(\mathbb R)= \big\{\,f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C\,\,\, \text{continuous and}\,\, \lim_{x\to \pm \infty}f(x)=0 \big\}.$$

Assume that $f\in C_{0}(\mathbb R)$.

**My question is**: 
Is it always true that, $\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)| dx < \infty ? $  If not, counter example ?

(**My attempt**: Since $f\in C_{0}(\mathbb R)$, so given $\epsilon >0$ there is a compact set $K\subset \mathbb R$  and $M> 0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for every $x\in K$ and $|f(x)|< \epsilon $ for every $x\in \mathbb R - K$; thus, $\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)| dx = \int_{K}|f(x)| dx + \int_{\mathbb R -K} |f(x)|dx \leq C + \epsilon \mu(\mathbb R - K)$, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ ;  but, certainly, this is incomplete argument !!)

Comment: Let $f$ be some continuous function (defined piecewise) that is eventually $1/x$.

Comment: It is not true. I'm not sure whether this is homework so I'll just say that much. Look for a counterexample. There are some very simple ones! Have fun.

Comment: False, this has also been discussed on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663230/int-0-infty-fx-dx-exists-then-lim-x-rightarrow-infty-fx-mu/663333#663333

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let for example
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|+1}.
$$
Then
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=\infty.
$$